# Python get two GPS point bearing

Tags: python, gps, bearing

Trying to get two gps coordinate bearing in degree, but get wrong result.
I think the problem is python math work in radiant, but when a convert to degrees got wrong result too.

The good result is around 30-33.
With this code, i get 0,75, when converting rad to deg, get 43.
There is my code:

```
import math

lat1 = 47.357818 
lon1 = 18.985417
lat2 = 47.369282 
lon2 = 18.996625
pi = 3.1415

X = math.cos(lat2) * math.sin(lon1-lon2)
Y = math.cos(lat1) * math.sin(lat2) - math.sin(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.cos(lon2-lon1)
B = math.atan2(X,Y)

print B
```

Help me please, what is the good method to convert?
ps: Sorry for my english.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [geopy](https://github.com/geopy/geopy).

Comment: Convert your lat\longs to radians. Then convert B from radians to degrees and you'll get 33.5

Comment: Im stupid, forgot to convert back. thanks. But now i get negative result ( -33.5091)